# JitsiMeetPlugin.kt: (66, 42): Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle, jitsi-meet

I plugin JitsiMeet but now I'm getting this error after giving all dependencies for this package.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':jitsi_meet:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 39s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goto the JitsiMeetPlugin.kt file and replace all the Activity with Activity? except package name and comment.

Answer (score 7):

I actually fixed the bug for them, Hope the CODEOWNER review it. It's just a `type_error`. It's very common error.

Error You got :

```
JitsiMeetPlugin.kt C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\
jitsi_meet-4.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\gunschu\jitsi_meet\
JitsiMeetPlugin.kt: (66, 42): 
Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected
```

What caused the error :

```kotlin
    constructor(activity: Activity) : this() {
        this.activity = activity
    }
```

Solution:

```kotlin
constructor(activity: Activity?) : this() {
        this.activity = activity
}
```

from here:
https://github.com/gunschu/jitsi_meet/blob/97154d582969af1155489bd066d280d85054e5c7/jitsi_meet/android/src/main/kotlin/com/gunschu/jitsi_meet/JitsiMeetPlugin.kt#L34

Reference: https://github.com/gunschu/jitsi_meet/issues/393

Answer (score 0):

How to go JitsiMeetPlugin.kt
C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\jitsi_meet-4.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\gunschu\jitsi_meet\JitsiMeetPlugin.kt: (66, 42): Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':jitsi_meet:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Put ? behind Activity in JitsiMeetPulgin.k file.